google looker studio - applying control to only select Metrics in a chart
Google Looker Studio (not enterprise)
I have a table imported from Big Query that stores support case related data.
This table has a column for "days open" while it was in Level 1 and another  column for "days open" when it was in Leve 2.
I built a basic chart with Metrics:

avg(L1_time) MTTR
avg(L2_time) MTTR
I have a Control to filter based on the technician. This control changes the values on the chart correctly when a value is selected.
I want to include 2 more metrics in the chart for
avg(L1_time) Team MTTR
avg(L2_time) Team MTTR
for all anaylsts. I cant seem to  find a way to add these Metrics and not have the Control NOT apply to these 2 metrics on the chart.


My Current chart options

I am not seeing any options to do this as far as I can tell.
